# Read Data From Text File PHP

Tags: php, file, text

I'm just wondering how I can read a text file in php, I'd like to have it display the last 200 entries (their each on a new line) from the text file.

Like

```
John White
Jane Does
John Does
Someones Name
```

and so on

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), or possibly just [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods for reading text from files in PHP.

You could use [fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), etc. Load the file into a dynamic array, then just output the last 200 elements of that array.

Answer (score 1):

[file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) will get the contents of a file and put it into an array. After that, it's like JYelton said, output the last 200 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This outputs last 200 rows. Last row first:

```
$lines = file("filename.txt");
$top200 = array_slice(array_reverse($lines),0,200);
foreach($top200 as $line)
{
    echo $line . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("file_name.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one character until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
   echo fgetc($myfile);
}

fclose($myfile);
?>
```

You may use this