# Read data from a text file, edit it and save it in PHP

Tags: php

I want to write a script which reads data from a text file, lets me edit it and then allows me to save the contents to a text file. 
I think I can load the file content in a text field to edit the file, though better suggestions are welcome .
 I want to load 10 lines at a time, edit them and then append them to a single output file
As of now I am just able to read data from the file.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$file = fopen("t.txt", "r");
$i = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file);
$members = explode('\n', $line_of_text);
var_dump($members);

}
fclose($file);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are able to just read the data because you written code to just read the data. which 10 lines you want to read them? first 10 lines?

Comment: fgets() reads a line of text. there'd be nothing to explode on, because you'd only have one line of text retrieved anyways. And if you want a better system: don't use files. use a database.

Comment: Read 10 lines at a time, edit them , save them. Then read the next 10 lines, edit them and append them. This continues until the whole file is read and edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read in 10 lines at a time, you do the following

```
$output = '';
$has_content = true;
while ($has_content) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    if (is_null($line)) {
      $has_content = false;
      break;
    }

    $processed_line = ...
    $output .= $processed_line;
  }
}
```

After closing the readable filehandle, you can write it back to the original file

```
$fh = fopen("t.txt", "w");
fwrite($fh, $output);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read entire file a single string using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Also, take a look on related question [Read Data From Text File PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648726/read-data-from-text-file-php).